# Return the fetch response from another file

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am trying to call a function that calls fetch to an API from a React component in a separate file and am not finding the correct solution to get the correct response back.

When I debug, the `result` returns before the `updateAccount` function has completed and the final result is never returned to my `update` function.

Inside the `fetch`, the API returns the correct response whether it is successful or has validation errors and those results are correctly assigned to `result.success` and `result.errors` but the `result` doesn't get returned from the function so that the caller can make use of those values.

Inside of my React component:

```
import { updateAccount } from '../services/requests';
...
const update = (account: EditAccountModel) => {
  const result = updateAccount(account);
  if(result.errors.length > 0) {
    // will notify of errors
    console.log(result.errors); // is an empty array instead of validation errors
  } else {
    // will notify of success
    console.log(result.success); // is an empty string instead of success message
  }
}
...
```

My request file

```
export const updateAccount = (account: EditAccountModel | undefined): EditAccountResponseModel => {
  const result = new EditAccountResponseModel();
  fetch(baseUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(account),
    headers 
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(response);
    }
    result.success = `${account?.name} was updated successfully!`
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (typeof error.json === "function") {
      error.json().then(jsonError => {
        result.errors.push(jsonError);
      }).catch(genericError => {
        result.errors.push(genericError);
      });
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` reassignment happens inside `then` `catch` but it won’t be affective in the way you expected. The guaranteed way to return correct result is via a `callback()` passed to your `updateAccount()` if you could afford it:

```js
export const updateAccount = (
  account: EditAccountModel | undefined,
  callback: Function
): EditAccountResponseModel => {

  const result = new EditAccountResponseModel();

  fetch(baseUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(account),
    headers 
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(response);
    }

    result.success = `${account?.name} was updated successfully!`
    callback(result);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (typeof error.json === "function") {
      error.json().then(jsonError => {
        result.errors.push(jsonError);
        callback(result);
      }).catch(genericError => {
        result.errors.push(genericError);
        callback(result);
      });
    }
    

  });
}
```

And inside your React component:

```
const update = (account: EditAccountModel) => {
  const handleResult = (res) => {
    // your result callback code
    // ...
  };

  updateAccount(account, handleResult);
  // ...
}
```

Alternative way that keeps your current structure is to change your current `updateAccount()` to an `async` function, then return `await fetch()`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your approach with the edits you suggested - the final callback(result) in the catch like that doesn't work tho because result is inside the block, I moved callback(result) inside to mitigate that error.
But now I am left with the fact that I no longer am returning from all paths in the function and receiving this error:
"A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."

Comment: So I changed the return to Promise<EditAccountResponseModel | any> to mitigate that but that also doesn't work - back in my function when evaluate result.errors that gives yet another error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')"
So it looks like result still isn't being populated or understood as the return from the function.

Comment: I was able to make this work - I simply created a separate function to handle the result and passed that into my function as the callback you suggested. I also left the original declaration of the result model at the top of the function to avoid declaring it in multiple places. I also moved the callback to just after each line where I push the errors into the array. Now I am getting both success and errors populated back in the callback function where I evaluate the result. Thanks!

Comment: @CDSmith Thank you very much for the update! I will update my answer accordingly to your suggestions for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the response . I'll let read more about how [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) work in JavaScript.
I wouldn't code `updateAccount` the same way you did, especially where you use the variable `result` and update it inside the flow of the promise (you really don't need that). You're also using React so you can use the state to store and update the result of the update function. But let's fix your problem first:

```
export const updateAccount = async (account: EditAccountModel | undefined): EditAccountResponseModel => {
  const result = new EditAccountResponseModel();
  await fetch(baseUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(account),
    headers 
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(response);
    }
    result.success = `${account?.name} was updated successfully!`
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (typeof error.json === "function") {
      error.json().then(jsonError => {
        result.errors.push(jsonError);
      }).catch(genericError => {
        result.errors.push(genericError);
      });
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

First make your function `updateAccount` `async` then `await` the result of the promise.

Now the same thing for the function `update`:

```
const update = async (account: EditAccountModel) => {
  const result = await updateAccount(account);
  if(result.errors.length > 0) {
    // will notify of errors
  } else {
    // will notify of success
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that doesn't work either for me (I have tried that approach) - I also have to change the return to Promise<EditAccountResponseModel> but the result is the exact same thing, the if block runs immediately and result.success and result.errors aren't being returned from the function.

Comment: I did forget to change my fetch to await fetch - that helped but the real solution was probably what you were hinting at with React/Promises, I supplied a separate callback function to the request method and that got me what I needed. Thanks for your help!